# How do I resolve an Inflating Error in Android

Tags: android, turbolinks

The app keeps crashing when I open it on an emulator. This is the activity_main.xml and the error I get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_host"
        android:name="com.example.test_run.MainSessionNavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="false" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.test_run:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.test_run:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.test_run:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the line with `android:name="com.example.test_run.MainSessionNavHostFragment"` ?